# How to concatenate 1000 images vertically using for loop in python?

Tags: python, image, concatenation, scikit-image

I want to concatenate vertically a lot of images. I used `skimage` to read images then in each iteration `io` read image and `vconcat` concatenate the new image on the old image vertically. The result of my code didn't concatenate the images, just combine the images. Any ideas how to make each image in each iteration concatenate vertically on each other?

I want to concatenate the first image and the second image vertically:

[image: fist image]

[image: second image]

but I got this result:

[image: result]

[image]

```
data = []
if nSpectogram < 3765:
    for k in range(0, 21):
        path = io.imread('E:\\wavelet\\spectrograms\\paz05\\'+'spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k+1)+'.png')
        im_v_array = np.array(im_v)
        data.append(path)
    res = np.concatenate(data)
    plt.imshow(res, cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between "concat" and "combine"? Examples will goa  long way w.r.t what you are getting and what you want

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan done. I want to concatenate a lot of images vertically. but i got image like the image i added in the post as a result. I  just want to concatenate the images vertically not to combine them.

Comment: So your result is a **single** image without x and y axes? I tried many ways and cannot reproduce.

Comment: @Parfait Exactly.it was a single image without x and y axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `skimage.io` (which may be due to a version or CPU issue), consider using [`matplotlib.pyplot.imread`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) with list comprehension or `map`. Below demonstrates with OP's two images.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_paths = ["OP_Image_1.png", "OP_Image_2.png"]

data = [plt.imread(img) for img in img_paths]
# data = list(map(mpimg.imread, img_paths))

res = np.concatenate(data)
plt.imshow(res, cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot Output]

---

Specifically, for OP's iteration of files:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...
spec_path = r"E:\wavelet\spectrograms\paz05"                     # RAW STRING FOR BACKSLASHES
spec_file = f"spec_{isPreictal}_{str(nSpectogram+1)}_{{}}.png"   # F STRING FOR INTERPOLATION

if nSpectogram <3765:
   data = [plt.imread(os.path.join(spec_path, spec_file.format(k+1))) for k in range(21)]

   res = np.concatenate(data)
   plt.imshow(res, cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
   
   plt.axis('off')
   plt.savefig(os.path.join(spec_path, "Output.png"))
```

Comment: But I have a lot of images not only 2. can i put `path` inside `img_paths`  to read each image in each iteration?

Comment: See extended answer for your current setup. Also, avoid printing to screen with `plt.show()` but save to file: `plt.savefig(...)`. Not sure why you want 1,000 concatenated images which may become a large file and take a while to process.

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 6):

Use -

```
merged_img = []
for i in range(3):
    img = io.imread('https://machinelearningblogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/849825_XL-830x400.jpg')
    merged_img.append(img)

merge = np.concatenate(merged_img)

plt.imshow(merge)
```

[image]

Just add all the images to a `list` in the `for` loop after reading them and pass the list to `np.concatenate`

Comment: it didn't work with me.
```
data=[]
if nSpectogram <3765:
            for k in range (0,21):
                path=io.imread('E:\\wavelet\\spectrograms\\paz05\\'+'spec_'+isPreictal+'_'+str(nSpectogram+1)+'_'+str(k+1)+'.png')
                im_v_array=np.array(im_v)
                plt.imshow(im_v,cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
data.append(path)
            res=np.concatenate(data)
```

Comment: I didn't work with me. I have edited my code in the post with you answer. please take a look on it.

Comment: @nadamedhat you have to `imshow()` the `res` object outside the loop. Please copy paste the solution provided as-is and check; post that adjust your code accordingly

Comment: @Vivek Kalyanarangan `imshow` and `res` are outside the loop. it didn't concatenate the images.

Comment: @Parfait I mean the images didn't concatenate vertically just sowing the image in a different look

Comment: @Parfait I will add the resulting image in the post now , please check it

Comment: @parfait Please check the last image I have added

Comment: @Parfait sorry i have forget to edit `imshow` and add `res` instead of `im_v` but i have edited in my code. I will remoce aspect and interpolation from imshow. I hope it will work

Comment: @Parfait unfortunately it didn't work . Any idea how to solve that ??